# Resizable window with resizable circle

Tags: c++

I have to make a resizable window with circle inside it,which should also be resizable i.e. if the window is made larger it should become larger and if it is made smaller then it becomes smaller.

I made a simple window using windows.h in c++ which is resizable.Now how should I resize the circle with respect to the window?

One approach I thought that if I get the current size of the window I will be able to adjust the radius accordingly.But....

For getting the current size of window I used GetWindowRect() but it only works when I stretch the window.When I contract it it does not work.

So please figure it out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you have to do it with C++? because if you use C# and wpf, it's so simple.

Comment: Only C++ is permitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with the `Width`, `Height` is not important since we have `Width` as the radius of the circle.

```
// Use SetWindows(Width 1~100, Height 1~100) in main()
void SetWindows(int Width,int Height){
    _COORD coord;
    coord.X=Width;
    coord.Y=Height;

    _SMALL_RECT Rect;
    Rect.Top=0;
    Rect.Left=0;
    Rect.Bottom=Height-1;
    Rect.Right=Width-1; //18

    HANDLE Handle=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);      // Get Handle
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(Handle,coord);           // Set Buffer Size
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(Handle,TRUE,&Rect);            // Set Window Size

    DrawCircle(Width);
}

void DrawCircle(int Radius){

    // Draw Circle here, radius provided

}
```

Comment: I have to resize the windows api not the console